# Problema ao receber array de retorno - Laravel / Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Quando eu executo `dd($var)`

```
#attributes: array:3 [▼
  "id" => "1"
  "department" => "TÉCNOLOGIA DA INFORMAÇÃO"
  "branch" => "BIGUAÇU"
]
```

Erro no Vue.js:

> app.js:42893 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

no final tem essas informações:

```
{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"department":"TÉCNOLOGIA

Raw expression: v-bind:items="{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"department":"TÉCNOLOGIA"
```

parece que quando chega no espaçamento dá problema.

Comment: Troque a aspas duplas da propriedade, por aspas simples: `v-bind:items='....'` veja se funciona

Comment: Deu certo amigo, valeu!!!